# How to organize C# code in different files without GUI?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm beginner to C# and have to develop some C# code under linux.
Until now, I could work it all out in a single file, just by using the two commands **mcs** and **mono**, without any GUI. And if possible, I'd like to avoid the GUI.

But now I want to seperate code in different files or even folders, but I could not find any explanation online.

Let's say I have some code like this

```
public class SpecialVector
{
// some code 
}
```

in some *special.cs* file. How can I use `SpecialVector` in some other file, let's say *normal.cs*? (Btw how do you call code grouped in a file in C#?)

Excuse me if this question has already been asked, but I don't know how to twist it so that the search engine understands my problem...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure

Comment: "C# code under linux" is .NET Core today, not Mono, so as a beginner don't waste your time in the wrong way.

Comment: @T.S. thx but that does not help me technically. As far as I can understand, it merrily explains that it is possible, not how the _.csproj_, _packages.config_ & and _.sln_ files are generated...

Comment: Switching to .NET Core will help you do just that as it provides commands like [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) to generate such files for you. However, if you for some reason are limited to using Mono (and apparently a very old version of it since today Mono uses `csc`), have a look at the [man page for `mcs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs). In essence, you just specify all files you want to compile in the command line, separated by spaces: `mcs File1.cs File2.cs` (and so on)

Comment: Thank you @VisualVincent ! the solution with **mcs** is good enough for now. I'll see later if I install _dotnet_ or not

Comment: All .net files are text files. you can create them yourself as long as you know the format. Which is not hard to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, if you aren't limited to Mono for a particular reason, you are highly encouraged to switch to .NET Core (now called *.NET* as of version 5). It has native support for both Windows, Mac and Linux, and comes with command line tools that allow you to create and build entire multi-file projects in a single command, without having to specify each individual file manually.

That being said, if you continue using Mono, you can specify multiple files to the compiler in the following manner:

```sh
mcs File1.cs File2.cs
```

(and so on)

Have a look at the [man page for `mcs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs) for more info.